# How does the FindElements.By Make My Code Flow Selenium C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, selenium

I have this project that im working on and the part that is making me go insane is where I need to pull data and add it to a textbox (Simple right?)

Let me explain and the show you the code

What it does is, its navigating to a website and then it pulls data from the "tbody tr" (I dont know what its called, I think its called an element)

and then it simply adds it to the textbox.

See, what I dont understand is, is this.

```
IList<IWebElement> movies = getTopFive.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tbody tr"));
```

To be more specific.

```
FindElements(By.CssSelector("tbody tr"));
```

To be even more specific

```
FindElements(By.CssSelector());
```

How do I know what the CssSelector can grab and can not grab, im pretty sure it cant print a picture, thats not its function. I need to understand what its function is and what it is capable of, I did not find any documents online to this, I found it for Java & Python but not for C#

```
private void label11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var getTopFive = new FirefoxDriver();
    getTopFive.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.tradingview.com/");

    IList<IWebElement> movies = getTopFive.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tbody tr"));



    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
    {
        activeTextBox.Text = movies[i].Text;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the method name -as well as the return type- implies, `FindElements()` is capable of returning *HTML elements*. Which element the method would return decided by selector argument it receives. In your particular example, the selector expression is a *CSS selector* (`By.CssSelector()`) which reads *match all `tr` elements that resides inside `tbody` element*.

For reference : [**Mozilla Develope Network**: Getting started with CSS >
Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Comment: Are attributes and elements the same thing?

Comment: @VinnyGarcia No, they are different. Consider for example : `<div class="row"></div>`, here `class` is attribute and `div` is element. More complete reference from MDN : [HTML attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) * [HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)

Comment: Oh okay! And what would " ="row" " be considered as?

Comment: @VinnyGarcia to be more specific, `class="row"` is attribute, `class` is the attribute name and `row` is the value

Comment: Okay I think I got it
An element is something that holds an attribute and the attribute always has a name? Also, thank you so much for explaining I've been at this for about 5 days now!